# rar file error (Too small block encountered)

Tags: extract, rar

As I was trying to open a rar file. It prompts me with an error.

How can I fix this? I searched for this error but it was about PC booting. Help please

Comment: maybe the size of your zip file is 0 bytes(empty)?

Comment: No it's not, it's 7.5 gb

Comment: You haven't specified the version of Ubuntu and Archive Manager you are using. But you can try to extract the .rar file using `7z` from command-line.